# Preparo una cena vs. preparo la cena

Tags: artículos

In the Spanish grammar book I study there was a task to translate the following sentence to Spanish: "I prepare dinner".

**I answered:** "Preparo **una** cena".
**Correct answer:** "Preparo **la** cena".

Why do we need to use definite article here? In my understanding, if the dinner is not ready yet, you can't refer to it with the definite article, you're preparing *some* dinner.

I know that in English we don't use artilcles with the names of meals.

Is there some grammar rule I'm missing in Spanish?

Comment: In colloquial English ‘I’m preparing *the* dinner’ (referring to todsy’s dinner) is pretty common

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We usually say "preparo la cena" because it is clear which dinner I am referring to: *today's dinner*. There is only one dinner today.

If the day when the dinner takes place is open, then "una cena" is more common:

- El que pierda la apuesta tiene que pagar una cena (*Whoever loses the bet must pay for a dinner*).

Answer (score 1):

*La cena* is the evening meal. If I say *preparo la cena*, I mean that I am preparing food to be eaten this evening, unless the context indicates that I am talking about a specific dinner for another day.

But if I say *preparo una cena*, you would probably need more information to know what I am talking about. It may mean that I am preparing a special meal, not necessarily for today, or arranging for one. For instance:

> Preparo una cena para el próximo sábado.

This means that I am arranging for a dinner next Saturday, maybe with some friends. I am not necessarily cooking for it; we might be going to a restaurant. If we both already know about that dinner, then I may use the determinate article:

> Preparo la cena para el próximo sábado.

When you say *I prepare dinner* in English, unless there are other context indications, you are talking about dinner for this evening, so the right translation is *preparo la cena*.